# Hide/Unhide actions icons based on state.vallue value reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to hide the `approved/disapproved` button if the `data.STATUS` is equal to `APPROVED` in `MaterialTable`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
{ID: 1, STATUS: "APPROVED"},
{ID: 2, STATUS: "FOR APPROVAL"},
{ID: 3, STATUS: "REJECTED"},
]);

<MaterialTable 
                icons={tableIcons}
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                title="List of Advisory"
                style={{
                    overflowX: 'auto'
                }}
actions={[
 {
                        icon: tableIcons.Edit,
                        tooltip: 'Edit Advisory',
                        onClick: (event, rowData) => selectedAdvisory(rowData, 'Edit')
                    },
{
                icon: tableIcons.Delete,
                tooltip: 'Delete Advisory',
                onClick: (event, rowData) => selectedAdvisory(rowData, 'Delete')
              },
                    {
                        icon: tableIcons.ThumbsUpDownIcon,
                        tooltip: 'Approved/Disapproved Advisory',
                        onClick: (event, rowData) => selectedAdvisory(rowData, 'ApproveDisapprove')
                    },

{
                icon: tableIcons.PageviewIcon,
                tooltip: 'Preview',
                onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You are about to view' + rowData.ADVISORYID)
              }

]}
                localization={{
                    header:{actions:'Actions'}
                }}
            />
```

I want to hide the `Approved/Disapproved` icon on action column if the `STATUS` is `APPROVED`.
Thank you in advance

Material UI: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/
Material table:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-table
https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started

Comment: Please use columns property in MaterialTable component. Then you can manage each icons according to the rowdata=>value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add/Put the action icons/buttons in columns property.

```
{ title: 'Actions', sorting: false, render: rowData =>
<Link to={`#`}
onClick={dosomething}
style={{display: rowData.state==='approved' ? 'none' : 'block'}}
onClick={dosomething}
<Approveicon>
</Link> }
```

so the actions per column can be controlled