# Dynamically hide/show icon on each rows based on the status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Scenario: I want to hide the approval button when the STATUS = APPROVED, else display approval button.

See below codes

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
{ID: 1, STATUS: "APPROVED"},
{ID: 2, STATUS: "FOR APPROVAL"},
{ID: 3, STATUS: "REJECTED"}]);


<MaterialTable
  icons={tableIcons}
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  title="List of Advisory"
  style={{overflowX: 'auto'}}
  actions={[
    {
      icon: tableIcons.Edit,
      tooltip: 'Edit Advisory',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => selectedAdvisory(rowData, 'Edit')
    },
    {
            icon: tableIcons.Delete,
            tooltip: 'Delete Advisory',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => selectedAdvisory(rowData, 'Delete')
    },
    {
            icon: tableIcons.ThumbsUpDownIcon,
            tooltip: 'Approved/Disapproved Advisory',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => selectedAdvisory(rowData, 'ApproveDisapprove')
    },
    {
            icon: tableIcons.PageviewIcon,
            tooltip: 'Preview',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You are about to view' + rowData.ADVISORYID)
    }
]}
localization={{
                header:{actions:'Actions'}
            }}
/>
```

I only want to display the approval icon on rows with 2 and 3 since they are the one who are not yet APPROVED.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer upon reading some comments on other related issues.

[Hide/Unhide actions icons based on state.vallue value reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542226/hide-unhide-actions-icons-based-on-state-vallue-value-reactjs/66558974#66558974)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got this running on a codepen, or something similar.. is there a way you can host it?

I imagine you should have no issue using a ternary operator here somewhere?

`data.status === "APPROVED" ? <(true) SHOW THIS> : <(false) SHOW THIS INSTEAD>`

Wrap the rows in the ternary operator - put the parts you want to show in the first section (true section), and the parts you want to show when it's not approved in the second.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator